# How to obtain variable values from a text file for use by a bash script?

Tags: bash, variables

I have a bash script, and I'd like it to read in the values of variables from a text file.

I'm thinking that in the text file where the values are stored, I'd use a different line for each variable / value pair and use the equals sign.

```
VARIABLE1NAME=VARIABLE1VALUE
VARIABLE2NAME=VARIABLE2VALUE
```

I'd then like my bash script to assign the value `VARIABLE1VALUE` to the variable `VARIABLE1NAME`, and the same for `VARIABLE2VALUE` / `VARIABLE2NAME`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the syntax of the file is the syntax you would use in the script itself, the `source` command should do the trick:

```
source text-file-with-assignments.txt
```

alternately, you can use `.` instead of `source`, but in a case like this, using the full name is more clear.

The documentation can be found in the [GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-source).

Comment: Yes, `source` is a synonym for `.`.  I updated my answer to cite this.